# Laravel: External API is using same database name used by API caller

Tags: laravel

I have two applications and both applications are developed on Laravel 8.x version. As per client requirement, I need to sync data from App1 to App2. So, I have created an API in APP2 that willrecieve data from App1 and then save into database. In App1, I am sending data to APP 2 using that API. To send data to this API, I am using Laravel HTTP client and also tried CURL earlier. In both cases, APP2 is using database of APP1. I mean, when APP2 recieve data from APP1  and try to save it then it is saved in APP1's database.

I am very confused why this is happening. For both APPs, codebase, database and URL all are different. For a moment, both APPs are running on my localhost but on different URL.

Can someone please let me know, what is wrong there?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the issue is based on the information you provided.

But it may be the case that the environment loader of laravel is using the sender's variables rather than the current ones.

I'd recommend you to try those two solutions:

1. Run `php artisan optimize` on both apps, then try to send, this will cache all configs making it load directly instead of from `.env`.
2. Try to hardcode the connection information in the `config/database.php` file, just to see if the problem truely is from laravel, or is it something else.